# Need help on calculating expansion of a series

Tags: sequences-and-series

I have tried to expand $(1-\frac12+\frac13-\frac14+...)^3=\ln^32$ when I reached
$$\frac34\zeta(3)+\mathrm{chunk}$$
Can anyone help to figure out what is on the right?

Comment: It is probably problematic to expand powers of ALTERNATING series. Here we do not even have an absolute convergent series.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the series $1-\frac12+\frac13-\frac14+\dots$ for $\log 2$ does not converge absolutely, you can't naively assume you can expand its cube and rearrange the terms.

However, what you can do quite easily is, for example, employ [Abel summation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Divergent_series#Abel_summation) for not-necessarily-convergent series instead.  Take the series
$$
\log (1+z)=z-\frac12z^2+\frac13 z^3-\dots
$$
cube it
$$
[\log (1+z)]^3=\sum_{n=3}^\infty(-1)^{n-3}z^n\sum_{\substack{n_1+n_2+n_3=n\\n_1,n_2,n_3\geq 1}}\frac1{n_1n_2n_3}
$$
and so taking out $n_1=n_2=n_3$ terms
\begin{align*}
[\log (1+z)]^3&=\sum_{n=1}^\infty (-1)^{n-1} n^{-3}z^{3n}\\
&\quad+\sum_{n=3}^\infty(-1)^{n-3}z^n\sum_{\substack{n_1+n_2+n_3=n\\n_1,n_2,n_3\geq 1\\\#\{n_1,n_2,n_3\}\neq 1}}\frac1{n_1n_2n_3}.
\end{align*}
So taking the radial limit $z\uparrow 1$, we have
$$
(\log2)^3=\frac34\zeta(3)+\sum_{n=1}^\infty(-1)^n b_n
$$
where the sum is taken in Abel's sense and
\begin{align*}
b_n&=\sum_{\substack{n_1+n_2+n_3=n+3\\n_1,n_2,n_3\geq 1\\\#\{n_1,n_2,n_3\}\neq 1}}\frac1{n_1n_2n_3}\\
&=\sum_{\substack{2n_1+n_2=n+3\\n_1\neq n_2\\n_i\geq 1}}\frac3{n_1^2n_2}+\sum_{\substack{n_1+n_2+n_3=n+3\\1\leq n_1<n_2<n_3}}\frac6{n_1n_2n_3}
\end{align*}
The first few terms are $b_1=\frac32$, $b_2=\frac74$, $b_3=\frac74$, $b_4=\frac{29}{15}$.